# How to merge strings pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying `merge` specific `strings` in a `pandas` `df`. The `df` below is just an example. The values in my `df` will differ but the basic rules will apply. I basically want to `merge` all `rows` until there's a 4 letter `string`.

Whilst the 4 letter string in this df is always `Excl`, my `df` will contain numerous 4 letter `strings`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['Include','Inclu','Incl','Inc'],
    'B' : ['Excl','de','ude','l'],           
    'C' : ['X','Excl','Excl','ude'],
    'D' : ['','Y','ABC','Excl'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Out:

```
         A     B     C     D
0  Include  Excl     X      
1    Inclu    de  Excl     Y
2     Incl   ude  Excl   ABC
3      Inc     l   ude  Excl
```

Intended Output:

```
         A     B     C     D
0  Include  Excl     X      
1  Include        Excl     Y 
2  Include        Excl   ABC
3  Include              Excl
```

So `row 0` stays the same as `col B` has 4 letters. `Row 1` merges `Col A,B` as `Col C` 4 letters. `Row 2` stays the same as above. `Row 3` merges `Col A,B,C` as `Col D` has 4 letters.

I have tried to do this manually by merging all `columns` and then go back and removing unwanted values.

```
df["Com"] = df["A"].map(str) + df["B"]  + df["C"]
```

But I would have to manually go through each row and remove different lengths of letters.

The above df is just an example. The central similarity is I need to merge everything before the 4 letter string.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: It's in there @aydow. Under Intended Output

Comment: not able to understand your output,like what happend to the data in Column D

Comment: Updated @experiment

Comment: Row 2, column A also has four letters; what decides that it is the four letter string in column C that decides what is merged?

Comment: Take the second 4 letter string.

Comment: But it looks like you are merging everything to the left of the first 4 letter string, but in the case of Row 2, there is a four letter word in the first column as well.

Comment: In the answer below, I went ahead and made the assumption that for this purpose, the first column is simply considered special.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks @fuglede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
mask = (df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(len) == 4).cumsum(1) == 0
df.A = df.A + df.iloc[:, 1:][mask].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(), 1)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:][~mask].fillna('')
```

Comment: Thanks @fuglede. I needed something that used any 4 letter `strings`. Not specifically `Excl`

Answer (score 1):

try this,

Sorry for the clumsy solution, I'll try to improve the performance ,

```
temp=df.eq('Excl').shift(-1,axis=1)
df['end']= temp.apply(lambda x:x.argmax(),axis=1)
res=df.apply(lambda x:x.loc[:x['end']].sum(),axis=1)
mask=temp.replace(False,np.NaN).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(False).astype(bool)
del df['end']
df[:]=np.where(mask,'',df)
df['A']=res
print df
```

Output:

```
         A     B     C     D
0  Include  Excl     X      
1  Include        Excl     Y
2  Include        Excl   ABC
3  Include              Excl
```

Improved solution:

```
res= df.apply(lambda x:x.loc[:x.eq('Excl').shift(-1).argmax()].sum(),axis=1)
mask=df.eq('Excl').shift(-1,axis=1).replace(False,np.NaN).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(False).astype(bool)
df[:]=np.where(mask,'',df)
df['A']=res
```

More simplified solution:

```
t=df.eq('Excl').shift(-1,axis=1)
res= df.apply(lambda x:x.loc[:x.eq('Excl').shift(-1).argmax()].sum(),axis=1)
df[:]=np.where(t.fillna(0).astype(int).cumsum() >= 1,'',df)
df['A']=res
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed Thasin ah but i'm getting an error. `TypeError: ("reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: sorry to hear that, but it works without a problem for me. It works on your sample data.

Comment: @Maxibon - check with the more simplified version

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a rough approach,
Here, we are finding the location of the 'Excl' and merging the column values up it so as to obtain our desired output.

```
ls=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    end=(df.loc[i,:].index[(df.loc[i,:]=='Excl')][0])
    ls.append(''.join(df.loc[i,:end].replace({'Excl':''}).values))
df['A']=ls
```